# Can i make Testing or Remote server in sublime3 like dreamweaver

Tags: connection, sublimetext3, dreamweaver

I recently started using Sublime Text 3. I always save my web development work in USB drive.

Can I make Testing or Remote server in sublime3 like Dreamweaver

**Mean's** Sublime3 save my Testing or Remote (connection = local/network) Server Folder in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite\

**and** 
Local Site Folder save in USB Drive **e.g.** x:\TestSite\

and I able to put and get files like Dreamweaver

How can I do this? I will greatly appreciate any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Synchronize Update Remote Server Files (Local/Network)**

Install package [SublimeSimpleSync](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeSimpleSync) with package control in sublime3, 
After Installation go and open Preference>Package Setting>SublimeSimpleSync a file and ADD THIS CODE & SAVE

```
{  
  "config": 
  {
   "autoSync": true,
   "debug": false,
   "timeout": 10  
  },
 "rules": 
  [
   {
    "type" : "local",
                           // Apache Server Folder
    "local" : "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TestSite\\", 

                           // Local Site Folder save in USB Drive 
    "remote" : "N:\\TestSite\\" 
   }
  ]
 }
```

> This package {SublimeSimpleSync} use to update your USB folder files when you edit and save in Apache server Folder...

**View In Browser {Configure to View on Local Server}**

Install another package [View In Browser](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/View%20In%20Browser) with package control in sublime3, After Installation open sublime project file e.g. "TestSite.sublime-project" and ADD THIS CODE & SAVE

```
"settings":
{
    "sublime-view-in-browser":
    {
        "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080\\",
        "basePath": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"
    }
}
```

> Here *localhost* can be root URL or IP and 8080 is port no.

Now open a page in sublime (which you want to render in sever) and right click and in menu click *View in Browser*

**Live Preview In Google Chrome Browser**

For Live preview in Google Chrome search Extension LivePage in chrome web store and install it. Its is very use full for most up-to-date version of a loaded web page when you change in editor.